# how to transmit multiple params in RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I use RxJava and Okhttp to download a file. For Example, I need the url for downloading the file and the name for creating name. But I can only get one param at one time.

Is there any way to get url and name at same time?

```
api.getRatedWallpapers()
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .map(wallpaper -> wallpaper.detail)
            .filter(details -> details != null && details.size() != 0)
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .filter(detail1 -> detail1.width > 1920)
            .map(detail -> detail.il_file)
            .map(s -> new Request.Builder().url(s).build())
            .map(client::newCall)
            .map(call -> {
                try {
                    return call.execute();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            })
            .map(response -> {
                try {
                    return response.body().byteStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            })
            .map(BufferedInputStream::new)
            .subscribe(bufferedInputStream -> {

                        //Here I should use the name in the Detail instance.
                        File file = new File(random.nextInt(10000) + ".jpg");
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
                            int hasRead;
                            while ((hasRead = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                fos.write(buffer, 0, hasRead);
                            }
                            fos.close();
                            bufferedInputStream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    },
                    Throwable::printStackTrace,
                    () -> System.out.println("Completed"));
```

Comment: Combine the various pieces of information into an object?

Comment: @chrylis thx，that should work.... But no "rxjava" way?

Answer (score 0):

Either combine both using a dedicated wrapper class, or use the [Zip](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#zip%28java.lang.Iterable,%20rx.functions.FuncN%29) operator.

Comment: Thanks, I use a wrapper class to solve this problem... I create a Wrapper class and make a instance outside of this observable, and this instance will get the name when observable do some operators.  and use this name data at later... :)

Comment: Or use ready class like Pair - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html